# How to get the elapsed minutes between to dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the total elapsed minutes between two date in sql,what I try gives me an error

```
Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query
```

Here is my code:
Endtime = 2014-08-01 15:00:00 and StartTime = 2014-07-31 10:00:00

```
SELECT (EndTime - StartTime) * 1440
FROM DowntimeEvent
WHERE EventId = 1;

24 * 60 = 1440
24 hours in a day * 60 minutes in an hour
```

Comment: Have you considered using `DATEDIFF` with the unit as minutes?

Comment: I don't know how to use functions in sql

Comment: Why did you down vote me,atleast I tried something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SQL's DATEDIFF() function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartTime,EndTime)
FROM DowntimeEvent
WHERE EventId = 1;
```

Comment: Oh it returns a negative value is it possible to make it a positive value?

Comment: My bad I just needed to swap the times around

Comment: No worries, glad to help!  Here is Microsoft's documentation on the function in care you're interested: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189794.aspx) is what you're looking for. eg:

```
select DATEDIFF(minute, StartTime, EndTime) from DowntimeEvent where EventId = 1
```